# Trying to matching a column of names in one df where they could be an exact or partial match of another df 'scolumn?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-2.7

**Goal**: If the name in df2 in row i is a sub-string or an exact match of a name in df1 in some row N and the state and district columns of row N in df1 are a match to the respective state and district columns of df2 row i, combine.

**Break down of data frame inputs:**

1. df1 is a time-series style data frame.
2. df2 is a regular data frame.
   3.df1 and df2 do not have the same length.
3. df1 Names contain initials,titles, and even weird character encodings.
4. df2 Names are just a combination of First Name, Space and Last Name.

My attempts have centered around taking into account 1. Names, Districts and State.

My approaches have tried to take into account that names in df1 have initials or second names, titles, etc whereas df2 is simply first and last names. I tried to use str.contains('A-za-z') to account for this difference.

```py
# Data Frame Samples

# Data Frame 1
CandidateName = ['Theodorick A. Bland','Aedanus Rutherford Burke','Jason Lewis','Barbara  Comstock','Theodorick Bland','Aedanus Burke','Jason Initial Lewis', '','']
State = ['VA', 'SC', 'MN','VA','VA', 'SC', 'MN','NH','NH']
District = [9,2,2,10,9,2,2,1,1]
Party = ['','', '','Democrat','','','Democrat','Whig','Whig']
data1 = {'CandidateName':CandidateName, 'State':State, 'District':District,'Party':Party }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data1)

print df1

#        CandidateName                District   Party             State
#0  Theodorick A. Bland           9                       VA
#1  Aedanus Rutherford Burke      2                       SC
#2  Jason Lewis                   2         Democrat          MN
#3  Barbara Comstock          10        Democrat          VA
#4  Theodorick Bland          9                       VA
#5  Aedanus Burke                 2                       SC
#6  Jason Initial Lewis           2         Democrat          MN
#7  ''                            1         Whig          NH
#8  ''                            1         Whig          NH

Name = ['Theodorick Bland','Aedanus Burke','Jason Lewis', 'Barbara Comstock']
State = ['VA', 'SC', 'MN','VA']
District = [9,2,2,10]
Party = ['','', 'Democrat','Democrat']
data2 = {'Name':Name, 'State':State, 'District':District, 'Party':Party}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = data2)

print df2

#   CandidateName        District   Party      State
#0  Theodorick Bland    9           VA
#1  Aedanus Burke           2           SC
#2  Jason Lewis             2   Democrat    MN
#3  Barbara Comstock    10  Democrat    VA
```

```py
# Attempt code
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = (df1.State, df1.District,df1.CandidateName.str.contains('[A-Za-z]')), right_on=(df2.State, df2.District,df2.Name.str.contains('[A-Za-z]')))
```

I included merging on District and State in order to reduce redundancies and inaccuracies. When I removed district and state from left_on and right_on, not did the output df3 increase in size with a lot of wrong matches.

Examples include CandidateName and Name being two different people:

Theodorick A. Bland sharing the same row as Jasson Lewis Sr.

Some of the row results with the Attempt Code above are as follows:

Header
key_0 key_1 key_2 CandidateName District_x Party_x State_x District_y   Name Party_y State_y
Row 6, index 4
MN  2   True    Jason Lewis     2   Democrat    MN  2   Jasson Lewis Sr.    Republican  MN

Row 11, index 3
3   VA  10  True    Barbara Comstock    10      VA  10  Barbara Comstock    Democrat    VA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `difflib` for this to create an artificial `key column` to merge on. We call this column `name`, like the one in `df2`:

```
import difflib
df1['Name'] = df1['CandidateName'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Name'])[0])
df_merge = df1.merge(df2.drop('Party', axis=1), on=['Name', 'State', 'District'])

print(df_merge)
              CandidateName State  District     Party              Name
0       Theodorick A. Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
1          Theodorick Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
2  Aedanus Rutherford Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
3             Aedanus Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
4               Jason Lewis    MN         2                 Jason Lewis
5       Jason Initial Lewis    MN         2  Democrat       Jason Lewis
6         Barbara  Comstock    VA        10  Democrat  Barbara Comstock
```

**Explanation** of `difflib.get_close_matches`. It looks for similar strings in df2. This is how the new `Name` column in df1 looks like:

```
print(df1)
              CandidateName State  District     Party              Name
0       Theodorick A. Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
1  Aedanus Rutherford Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
2               Jason Lewis    MN         2                 Jason Lewis
3         Barbara  Comstock    VA        10  Democrat  Barbara Comstock
4          Theodorick Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
5             Aedanus Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
6       Jason Initial Lewis    MN         2  Democrat       Jason Lewis
```

Comment: So it turns out that I forgot to include the possibility of having empty cells. What would you recommend if there are multiple empty cells in df1 name column? I tried modifying the first column by replacing the empty cells with the string 'EMPTY' to see if it would work, however I still get **IndexError**: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you post a new question for this and describe in more detail? You can copy and paste the link of your new question here and I will have a look.

Comment: Here is the link [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445922/how-can-i-create-an-artificial-key-column-for-merging-two-datasets-using-difflab . I hope this clarifies the matter.