# How can I create an artificial key column for merging two datasets using difflab when the column of interest has missing cells?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-2.7, difflib

***Goal***: If the name in df2 in row i is a sub-string or an exact match of a name in df1 in some row N and the state and district columns of row N in df1 are a match to the respective state and district columns of df2 row i, combine.

I was recommended of using difflib to create an artificial key column to merge on.

This new column is called 'name'. difflib.get_close_matches looks for similar strings in df2.

This works well when all rows in the 'CandidateName' column are present but I get IndexError: list index out of range when a cell is missing.

I tried resolving this issue by filling in the empty column with the string 'EMPTY'. However the same error still occurs.

```py
# I used this method to replace empty cells
df1['CandidateName'] = df1['CandidateName'].replace('', 'EMPTY')


# I then proceeded to run the line again
df1['Name'] = df1['CandidateName'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Name'])[0])
```

```py
# Data Frame Samples

# Data Frame 1
CandidateName = ['Theodorick A. Bland','Aedanus Rutherford Burke','Jason Lewis','Barbara  Comstock','Theodorick Bland','Aedanus Burke','Jason Initial Lewis', '','']
State = ['VA', 'SC', 'MN','VA','VA', 'SC', 'MN','NH','NH']
District = [9,2,2,10,9,2,2,1,1]
Party = ['','', '','Democrat','','','Democrat','Whig','Whig']
data1 = {'CandidateName':CandidateName, 'State':State, 'District':District,'Party':Party }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data1)

print df1

#        CandidateName         District   Party          State
#0  Theodorick A. Bland           9                       VA
#1  Aedanus Rutherford Burke      2                       SC
#2  Jason Lewis                   2       Democrat        MN
#3  Barbara Comstock             10       Democrat        VA
#4  Theodorick Bland              9                       VA
#5  Aedanus Burke                 2                       SC
#6  Jason Initial Lewis           2         Democrat      MN
#7  ''                            1         Whig          NH
#8  ''                            1         Whig          NH

Name = ['Theodorick Bland','Aedanus Burke','Jason Lewis', 'Barbara Comstock']
State = ['VA', 'SC', 'MN','VA']
District = [9,2,2,10]
Party = ['','', 'Democrat','Democrat']
data2 = {'Name':Name, 'State':State, 'District':District, 'Party':Party}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = data2)

print df2

#   CandidateName        District   Party      State
#0  Theodorick Bland        9                   VA
#1  Aedanus Burke           2                   SC
#2  Jason Lewis             2       Democrat    MN
#3  Barbara Comstock        10      Democrat    VA

import difflib
df1['Name'] = df1['CandidateName'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Name'])[0])

df_merge = df1.merge(df2.drop('Party', axis=1), on=['Name', 'State', 'District'])
```

Expected

```py
print(df1)
#              CandidateName State  District     Party              Name
#0       Theodorick A. Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
#1  Aedanus Rutherford Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
#2               Jason Lewis    MN         2                 Jason Lewis
#3         Barbara  Comstock    VA        10  Democrat  Barbara Comstock
#4          Theodorick Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
#5             Aedanus Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
#6       Jason Initial Lewis    MN         2  Democrat       Jason Lewis
#7                              NH         1      Whig    
#8                              NH         1      Whig
```

Actual Error Result:

```py
-> 3194 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
---> 23 df1['Name'] = df1['CandidateName'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Name'])[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `list` type object back. And these lists dont have index `0`. Thats why you get this error.  Second of all, we need to convert these `lists` to type `string` to be able to do the merge like following:

*note*: you dont have to use: `df1['CandidateName'] = df1['CandidateName'].replace('', 'EMPTY')`

```
import difflib
df1['Name'] = df1['CandidateName'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Name'])))

df_merge = df1.merge(df2.drop('Party', axis=1), on=['Name', 'State', 'District'], how='left')

print(df_merge)
              CandidateName State  District     Party              Name
0       Theodorick A. Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
1  Aedanus Rutherford Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
2               Jason Lewis    MN         2                 Jason Lewis
3         Barbara  Comstock    VA        10  Democrat  Barbara Comstock
4          Theodorick Bland    VA         9            Theodorick Bland
5             Aedanus Burke    SC         2               Aedanus Burke
6       Jason Initial Lewis    MN         2  Democrat       Jason Lewis
7                              NH         1      Whig                  
8                              NH         1      Whig
```

**Note** I added `how='left'` argument to our `merge` since you want to keep the shape of your original dataframe.

**Explanation of `''.join()`**
We do this to convert the list to string, see example:

```
lst = ['hello', 'world']

print(' '.join(lst))
'hello world'
```